# Read array on sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-multiselectlistpreference

im using MultiSelectListPreference and the values save on array..

How can read??

```
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Set<String> a = pref.getStringSet("tabs", null);

    for ( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("salida", a[i]);
    }
```

i get this error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Set

Comment: the square bracket notation only works on array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [`Set`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html), and since it isn't an array, the square brackets (`[]`)are cannot be used to access indexes.

To easily read the values from the `Set`,use the enhanced for loop:

```
for (String str: a){
  Log.d("salida", str);
}
```

If you want to remove items from that Set as you loop through, you will have to use an [`Iterator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator.html), as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110425/1815485) answer.

Alternatively, if you want an array, you can use [`Set#toArray()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29):

```
String [] prefStrings = a.toArray(new String[a.size()]);
```

Then you can use the square brackets (`prefStrings[position]`) to access an index.