# How to subSet from SortedSet<String>

Tags: java, collections, subset, sortedset

I have to write a code that makes it possible to delete all the words of a SortedSet starts with K.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deleter {
    
    public static void deleteKWords(SortedSet<String> set) {
        set.subSet("K", "");
}
    }
    
}
```

I've heard that with a subSet can simple solved but i couldn't.

Comment: Read the javadoc of [`subSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet-E-E-) and [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#clear--), then combine them: `set.subSet("K", "L").clear()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110404/remove-elements-from-a-hashset-while-iterating

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive what you want by using Java 8 stream:

```
public static SortedSet<String> deleteKWords(SortedSet<String> set) {
   return new TreeSet<>(set
           .stream()
           .filter((s) -> !s.startsWith("K"))
           .collect(Collectors.toSet()));

}
```

Edit:
Probably it will be more efficient to avoid creating new object every time and just modify the one you send to the method:

```
 public static SortedSet<String> deleteKWords(SortedSet<String> set) {
    set.removeAll(set
            .stream()
            .filter((s) -> s.startsWith("K"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return set;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by combining subSet() and removeAll() methods:

```
public static void deleteKWords(SortedSet<String> set) {
    Set s = new TreeSet<>(set.subSet("K", "O"));
    set.removeAll(s);
}
```