# Removing a set from it self while iterating

Tags: java, set

I've been stuck on this for awhile now.  I am trying to remove elements of a set if they make a set criteria.  However when iterating when I try to remove the element it fails.

I get the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
private static void smallerSet(Set<Map<String, Int>> set){

    for (Map<String, Integer> map : set){

        for (String String : map.keySet()){

            if ( true){
                set.remove(map);

            }
            else{
                //System.out.println("test");


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110404/remove-elements-from-a-hashset-while-iterating

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove elements from a `Collection` while iterating over it with the enhanced for loop.

You should use an explicit `Iterator` and remove with the `Iterator`'s `remove()` method:

```
Iterator<Map<String, Integer>> iter = set.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext ()) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = iter.next();
    for (String str : map.keySet()){
        if (some condition) {
            iter.remove();
            break; // you should probably break from the inner loop
                   // after removing an element
        } else {
            //System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```