# Iterating over a HashSet and removing multiple elements in each iteration

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

In the following code, I am trying to get a `Set` of [circular primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_prime) up to `maxPlusOne`.

```
Set<Integer> primes = getPrimes(maxPlusOne); //Returns a set of all primes up to maxPlusOne ont including it
    Set<Integer> circularPrimes = new HashSet<>();

    Iterator<Integer> it = primes.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Set<Integer> perms = getAllRotations(it.next()); //Returns all rotations of an integer 123 => {123, 231, 312}

        if(primes.containsAll(perms)) {
            circularPrimes.addAll(perms);
            // Here I want to do something to the effect of removing all elements in perms from primes
        }
    }
```

Now inside the `if` statement I want to remove *all* elements in `perms` from `primes`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110425/802339) answer shows how to remove one element that the `iterator` is pointing to. Is it even possible to remove *multiple* elements from `circularPrimes` in one iteration? If yes, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Iterator allows you to remove only the current element. For your case, you need not remove anything. I believe the reason you would like to remove is to avoid calling `circularPrimes` for a number that is a circular prime of a previously encountered number. In that case, you can simply check if the number is already part of the `circularPrimes` set - if yes don't call `getAllRotations`

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer currentNum = it.next();
    if (!circularPrimes.contains(currentNum)) {
        Set<Integer> perms = getAllRotations(currentNum); 

        if(primes.containsAll(perms)) {
            circularPrimes.addAll(perms); 
        }
    }

}
```